# Static Id - ASP.NET Core Distributed Cache Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, distributed-caching

We are using ASP.NET Core Distributed Cache Tag Helper with SQL server.

```
<distributed-cache name="MyCacheItem1" expires-after="TimeSpan.FromDays(1)">
   <p>Something that will be cached</p>
   @DateTime.Now.ToString()
</distributed-cache>
```

It stores as below.
[image]

The problem is that Id column is automatically hashed. we want some meaningful string in Id column.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Fei Han. I got clue from your answer.

To store custom string in Id column. Follow the steps.

1. Implement custom class using IDistributedCacheTagHelperService ( I created like HtmlDistributedCacheTagHelperService)
2. Inject this custom class in startup.
   services.AddScoped<IDistributedCacheTagHelperService,    HtmlDistributedCacheTagHelperService>();
3. Copy actual source code of DistributedCacheTagHelperService (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/Cache/DistributedCacheTagHelperService.cs#L102). and paste inside HtmlDistributedCacheTagHelperService.
4. I added custom attribute htmlcache-uniqueid.
   <distributed-cache name="UniqueName"  **htmlcache-uniqueid="CustomStringId"**>
5. Inside HtmlDistributedCacheTagHelperService class i added below code to get my custom attribute.

   ```
    if (output.Attributes != null && output.Attributes.Count > 0 &&
    string.Equals(output.Attributes[0].Name, "htmlcache-uniqueid") && 
    output.Attributes[0].Value != null)
   {
    storageKey = Convert.ToString(output.Attributes[0].Value);
   }
   ```
6. finally you can see id stored in db like below.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that Id column is automatically hashed.

From the source code, we can find it seems a by-design behavior:

```
try
{
    var serializedKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.GenerateKey());
    var storageKey = key.GenerateHashedKey();
    var value = await _storage.GetAsync(storageKey);

    //...

    //...

    await _storage.SetAsync(storageKey, encodeValue, options);
```

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/DistributedCacheTagHelper.cs#L72
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/52eff90fbcfca39b7eb58baad597df6a99a542b0/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/Cache/DistributedCacheTagHelperService.cs#L102

> we want some meaningful string in Id column. Is it possible?

If you have specific scenario/requirement that requires unhashed data for `Id` column, you can refer to the source code of `DistributedCacheTagHelper` and `DistributedCacheTagHelperService`, then implement a custom tag helper.